# android project not resolving and reseting androids studio doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a problem where files that should be showing up in my android project are not appearing. For example, in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pencil"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable-mdpi/pencil"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eraser"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable-mdpi/eraser"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get errors for the pencil and eraser src lines, despite having the two bitmap images in that exact folder (and being able to see it in my directory). Similar problems exist for this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class DrawingActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(res.menu.drawing, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == res.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Where it cannot find drawing.xml (at line with res.menu.drawing), even though again it is visible in the directory.

Is there something else I'm supposed to do first? Maybe some kind of import beyond putting the items in the folder and rebuilding? I've read in some other cases that these kinds of problems were resolved by exiting and re-opening Android Studio, but I've now done that twice with no effect (as well as multiple cleans and rebuilds of the project). As such, I can only assume that I'm missing something more essential.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Determined part of the problem. The images are supposed to be handled with 'android:drawable' or 'android:background' (this is what I used). The other problem still stands however.

Comment: Okay, got the other one figured out too. For some reason, the program didn't get it until I wrote out 'layout.fragment_name' and had it autocomplete the line, at which point the statement became 'R.layout.fragment_name' and everything was fine.